# RHEL6 LDAP client not listing all the groups

Tags: linux, ldap, redhat, rhel

Using sssd I have a RHEL6 client configured to login using ldaps. The login works, but if the user logged is assigned to more than 1 group at the ldap level, groups  only returns 1 group? Could I be missing a configuration somewhere?
The group shown is the default group assigned to the user. In RHEL5 client, the group command display all the groups that are assigned to the user.

Comment: You could get more help if you revealed more about your setup. Do all the groups have a gidNumber assigned?

Comment: @jeemster yes all have gidNumber assigned. I would be glad to provide you with specifics about the setup. Let me know what exactly you are looking for and I can document it here. It is a straight forward openLdap server running on RHEL5.

Comment: As the LDAP account used from the RHEL6 Client, can you locate the groups with the same LDAP Query from the command line? (This would check permissions  within LDAP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to spend some time today and was able to fix the issue. RHEL 6 uses *sssd*. The configuration file `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` had to be changed to have the following in the domain/default section

```
ldap_search_base = dc=domain,dc=something,dc=com
ldap_group_member = uniquemember
```

Is the missing changes in the default config.

```
[domain/default]
ldap_tls_reqcert = never
auth_provider = ldap
ldap_schema = rfc2307bis
krb5_realm = EXAMPLE.COM
ldap_search_base = dc=domain,dc=something,dc=com
ldap_group_member = uniquemember
id_provider = ldap
ldap_id_use_start_tls = False
chpass_provider = ldap
ldap_uri = ldaps://yourldap.server.com/
ldap_chpass_uri = ldaps://yourldap.server.com/
krb5_kdcip = kerberos.example.com
cache_credentials = True
ldap_tls_cacertdir = /etc/openldap/cacerts
entry_cache_timeout = 600
ldap_network_timeout = 3
ldap_access_filter = (&(objectclass=shadowaccount)(objectclass=posixaccount))
```

Answer (score 1):

In general the things to check are:

1) Is the LDAP schema the one you want to use? (RFC2307 vs RFC2307bis). The former stores the plain username in the "memberuid" attribute, the latter (used by AD for instance) stores the full DN in the "member" attribute.

2) Are the search bases set correctly?

If you can paste the RHEL6 and RHEL5 config files for comparison, that would be great. Feel free to sanitize/remove info like bind DNs, passwords or URIs.

Comment: I checked the attribute and the username is set as memberUid on the server. Search bases are correct. The only difference in the ldap.conf is ssl start_tls (RHEL 6) and ssl yes (RHEL 5).